# Find specific value inside a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find a specific word inside a span tag.
The `<span>` is inside a `<pre>`.
I want to get the "6" from the code below.

```
<span class="infos">Scale: Ab Major
Time Signature: 6/8
Tempo: 80
Suggested Strumming: DU,DU,DU,DU
</span>
```

I also want to get the "80" as well and put it into an `<input>`.
The values of `Tempo` and `Time Signature` keeps on varying, so a simple search and retrieve didn't work.

I have tried so many methods suggested on SO, but nothing seems to help me with it.

This is the code that came closest. But it didn't help.

```
<script>
$("span:contains('Tempo:')").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(Tempo:)/g, '<span class="tem">$1</span>');
});
</script>

<span class="infos">Scale: Ab Major
 Time Signature: 6/8
 Tempo: 80
  Suggested Strumming: DU,DU,DU,DU
</span>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: one dirty regular expression, if you need it, that will get 1st group of digit between Signature and /, 2nd group digit after Tempo:  > `/Signature:\W(\d+)\/\d+\nTempo:\W(\d+)/`

Comment: You don't say what you want to do with the `6` that you say you "*want to get*," do you need those answering to do something with that? Replace it, move it, store it in a variable..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the answer of Barmer to find the 'Time Signature' value.

I think this may help you.

```js
$("span.infos").html(function(_, html) {
  var searchWord = 'Time Signature:';
  var searchWordlen = searchWord.length;
  var lastIndexofSearchWord = html.lastIndexOf(searchWord) + searchWordlen;
  var timeSignature = html.substring(lastIndexofSearchWord, html.lastIndexOf("/"));
  timeSignature = parseInt(timeSignature); //here is your value
  alert(timeSignature);
  return html.replace(/Tempo: (\d+)/, '<span class="tem">Tempo: <input name="tempo" value="$1"></span>');
});
```

```css
.infos {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="infos">Scale: Ab Major
 Time Signature: 6/8
 Tempo: 80
  Suggested Strumming: DU,DU,DU,DU
</span>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I created a simple .html file on my computer, pasted this code, and opened the page in Chrome. But nothing is happening. The Debug Console is also showing nothing. Could you tell me what I did wrong?

I've put the tags<script> and <style> as well in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the capture group to get the part that varies, not the part that's constant, so you can copy the variable part into the appropriate place in the replacement.

```js
$("span:contains('Tempo:')").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/Tempo: (\d+)/, '<span class="tem">Tempo: <input name="tempo" value="$1"></span>');
});
```

```css
.infos {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="infos">Scale: Ab Major
 Time Signature: 6/8
 Tempo: 80
  Suggested Strumming: DU,DU,DU,DU
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If each info is on a different line, here's a solution :

```
var infosList = $(".infos").text().split('\n');
var time = infosList[1].split(":")[1].trim().split("/");
//time : [6,8]
var tempo = infosList[2].split(":")[1].trim();
//tempo : 80
```

Here's a JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kgyzneeh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use this way:

```
var formatted_data = new Array();;
var info_data = $(".infos").html().split("\n"); 
$.each( info_data, function( index, value ){
    var data = value.split(":");
    formatted_data[data[0]]=$.trim(data[1]);
});
$("#time_signature").html(formatted_data["Time Signature"]);
$("#tempo").html(formatted_data["Tempo"]);
```

This way you can retrieve all the data in info span.

You can also refer the below JSFiddle for the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman_chhabra/nvs16wr1/